# Regex to match MediaWiki template without certain named parameter

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, mediawiki-templates

I’ll get to the point: I need a regex that matches any template out of a list *that have a `date` parameter* - so assuming that my (singleton for now) list of templates is “stub”, the things below that are in bold should be matched:

- **`{{stub}}`**
- **`{{stub|param}}`**
- `{{stub|date=a}}`
- `{{stub|param|date=a}}`
- `{{stub|date=a|param}}`
- `{{stub|param|date=a|param}}`
  Note: “param” means *any number* of parameters there.

Additionally, it would be nice if it could also match if the date parameter is blank, but this is not required.

The current regex I have so far is

```
{{((?:stub|inaccurate)(?!(?:\|.*?\|)*?\|date=.*?(?:\|.*?)*?)(?:\|.*?)*?)}}
```

However it matches the fourth and sixth items in the list above.

Note: `(?:stub|inaccurate)` is just to make sure the template is either a `stub` or `inaccurate` template.

Note 2: the flavor of regex here is Python 2.7 module RE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's enough to have a negative look-ahead, which tries to match date at any position?

`{{((?:stub|inaccurate)(?!.*\|date=).*)}}`

If empty date parameters have a `|` following the equals sign, then use

`{{((?:stub|inaccurate)(?!.*\|date=[^|}]).*)}}`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python, you have the luxury of [an actual parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwparserfromhell):

```
import mwparserfromhell
wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse('{{stub|param|date=a|param}}')
for template in wikicode.filter_templates():
    if template.get('date')...
```

That will remain accurate even if the template contains something you would not have expected (`{{stub| date=a}}`, `{{stub|<!--<newline>-->date=a}}`, `{{stub|foo={{bar}}|date=a}}` etc.). The [classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/323407) on the dangers of using regular expressions to parse complex markup applies to wikitext as well.

Comment: Oh, cool! I'll use this answer if the problem of unexpected markup crops up but it's not very likely considering the wiki I'm dealing with. I'll keep this in mind though!